# How can I modify my program to make the histogram vertical? I'm having trouble making it vertical. Code is below

Tags: c++

Having trouble making the histogram vertical. How can I modify my program to make the histogram vertical? Please help me Thank you! This is the code. This histogram is horizontal but I cannot figure out how to make it vertical. Making a histogram vertical is more challenging. I have tried many ways but it seems like everything I try I messed up the code and it does not work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // these 2 arrays will be used to count the letters in string
    char letterArray[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y','z' };
    int letterCountArray[26];

    string userInputString;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        letterCountArray[i] = 0;
    }
    
    cout << "****************************************THIS IS MY FREQUENCY PROGRAM*****************************************\n\n";
    cout << "Please input your sentence: ";
    getline(cin, userInputString);
    int lengthOfString = userInputString.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfString; i++) {
        char letter = tolower(userInputString[i]);
        //finding this letter in letterArray so we can get it's position number and increment in counter array
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            if (letterArray[j] == letter) {
            
                letterCountArray[j] = letterCountArray[j] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // showing result
    cout << "\n\n***** Showing Result *****\n";
    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout <<"\n"<< "We have calculated the frequency of letters succuessfully and accurately for you\n\n";
    cout <<"\n"<< "See Below\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (letterCountArray[i] > 0) {
            cout << "The letter '" << letterArray[i] << "' occurrs " << letterCountArray[i] << " times.\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    // showing histogram
    cout << "\n***** This is the Histogram: *****\n";
    // loop to display numbers and *
    for (int i = 15; i >0 ; i--) {
        cout.width(2);
        cout << i <<"|";
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            if (letterCountArray[j] == i) {
                cout << "* ";
                letterCountArray[j] = letterCountArray[j] - 1;
            }
            else {
                cout << "  ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }   
    cout << "   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        cout << "--";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   ";
    // displaying letters from letterArray
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        cout << letterArray[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    // stopPING the screen from dissappearing immideatly 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I have tried many ways but it seems like everything I try I messed up the code and it does not work."_ seems to describe a problem, but you have not shown the code related to that, nor the output that "does not work".  Please narrow down specifically what you're having difficulty with, show what you've tried, show what it outputs, show what you _expect_ it to output, and someone can surely help.  Otherwise, a perfectly valid solution could be "turn your screen on its side".

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

I started with changing the order of loops: letters first, counts after that.
Then I changed the direction of both loops.
Then I made some adjustments to the number of spaces and dashes when printing stars and lines.

```
    cout << "\n***** This is the Histogram: *****\n";
    // loop to display numbers and *
    for (int j = 25; j >= 0; --j) {
        cout << letterArray[j] <<"|";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 15 ; ++i) {
            if (letterCountArray[j] >= i) {
                cout << " * ";
            }
            else {
                cout << "   ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }   
    cout << "  ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        cout << "---";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "  ";
    // displaying letters from letterArray
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        cout.width(2);
        cout << i <<" ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    // stopPING the screen from dissappearing immideatly
```